# URL parameter value passed to PHP WordPress body_class

Tags: php, wordpress, url-parameters

I'm looking to pass a single value from a URL parameter to the page body as a class. In this instance the URL parameter is `utm_campaign` and I'd like to make append its value as a body class in WordPress.

I feel like where I'm off is in setting up the filter. Any help is appreciated, and since I'm learning, if you could explain, that would be even better. Thank you!

```
<?php

$utm_campaign = false;
if(isset($_GET['utm_campaign'])){
    $utm_campaign = $_GET['utm_campaign'];
}

function wp_body_classes( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'utm_campaign';
      
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','wp_body_classes' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this code out with my WP site and it worked fine. The only edit is to move your $_GET conditional logic to inside your action hook.

Also, as @SallyCJ pointed out, you probably want to include the utm-campaign name as a class. So this will add a generic 'utm_campaign' class and the dynamic `$utm_campaign` class since you might have common styles for all UTM campaign landing pages.

```
<?php

function wp_body_classes( $classes ) {
    if(isset($_GET['utm_campaign'])){
      $classes[] = 'utm_campaign';
      $classes[] = $_GET['utm_campaign'];
    }      
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','wp_body_classes' );
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$classes[] = $utm_campaign;` or just `$classes[] = $_GET['utm_campaign'];`..?

Comment: @SallyCJ - true. I was following the original code but in retrospect both should be added to the class list. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still isn't working for me, I'm going to check a few more things on my end. Caching is disabled..